# Validation for calender control of RadDatePicker (Telerik Controls)

Tags: asp.net, raddatepicker

I want to validate the RadDatePicker when a date is selected. User should not select greater than a particular date ? How can I restrict user from selecting a date which is not greater than a particular date.

Particular date populated from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [CompareValidator Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db330ayw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).Just note to compare to your date  (`ValueToCompare`) instead of (`ControlToCompare`) and set the type. By default it's `string` as i remember.so you need to set it to Date.Also look to this [page](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/calendar/examples/datepicker/validation/defaultcs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

On your other question:

> How can I restrict user from selecting a date which is not greater than a particular date.

In C#:

```
RadDatePicker1.MaxDate = myMaxDateTimeVariable;
```

or client-side:

```
var radDatePicker1 = $find("<%= RadDatePicker1.ClientID %>");
radDatePicker1.set_maxDate(myMaxDate);
```